# oracle equivalent of patindex and instr function with wild card characters

Tags: oracle

is there an oracle equivalent of `patindex`? from my search, the only function that is close to `patindex` is oracle's `instr` function but it does not support wild card.

what is the oracle equivalent of the following query?

```
select patindex('%[^0]%','00194505022')
```

edit: i found out `regexp_instr` have the similar function as `patindex`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's regexp_instr that uses standard regular expression syntax for pattern matching.

```
select regexp_instr('00194505022','[^0].*') from dual;
```