# ORA-00904: "PATINDEX": invalid identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the index of the first space in my string but,  I keep getting this error:

> ORA-00904: "PATINDEX": invalid identifier

Here is what I'm doing:

```
SELECT SUBSTR( FirstAuthor,  PATINDEX('% %',FirstAuthor), 20) AS first name
```

How can I use `PATINDEX()` in my code?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769350/oracle-equivalent-of-patindex-and-instr-function-with-wild-card-characters

Comment: PATINDEX is a T-SQL function.  A cursory glance at the Oracle documentation would have revealed its absence from the list of valid functions: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/index.htm#P   Although I admit the new layout of the Table Of contents makes it harder to find the Oracle equivalent :(  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions002.htm#CJAEEJFC

Answer (score 5):

I don't think `PATINDEX` exists in Oracle.  Try using [`InStr()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/instr.php) instead.

As a side note, I had to guess on Oracle based on the error code.  **Always include your RDBMS in your questions!**

Answer (score 3):

That looks like an Oracle error message, but PATINDEX isn't an Oracle function...  Try using [`regexp_instr`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions114.htm) instead.